# How to invoke an .exe in windows using task scheduler when the internet browser (ie or firefox) starts?

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks

How to invoke an .exe in windows using task scheduler when the internet browser (ie or firefox) starts

Comment: You just pasted your subject line. You have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

This seems somewhat like a lazy question.

1. Either write a Windows API (Win32 or perhaps C#) program which monitors running process list for the given browser starting, and then triggers a specified executable,  or
2. Write a program in another language, using shell-calls to the OS command-line utilities.. and use those to check for the browser process before triggering the specified executable,  or
3. Instruct the person/user/employee to launch the executable manually.